# Change variables dynamically in laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js

I have navbar in laravel (+vue.js) as a blade.php. I want to have in this navbar variable like {{xyz}} and when I am going on another page I can set text in Vue.js or something like this. Can you help me?

Code:

```
vue:
        data() {
            return {
                title: 'test',
            }
        },

and blade:
<nav class="navbar">
<div class="navbar-inner">
    <a href="xyz">xxx</a>
    <p style="text-align:center; color:white;">@{{ title }}</p>
    <button>        </button>
</div>
```

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: {{ test }}

and in vue 
test: "nameofpage', 

but that's not working

Comment: post all codes that are relevant to your issue bro. so we won't assume things :)

Answer (score 0):

Do not use the `php` variable, set a ***vue*** variable for that `php` variable instead. Something like:

```
// Vue instance ...
    data: {
        test: '{{ test }}',
    }
```

and then use it in html like:

```
<p> @{{ test }} </p>
```

Update:

You might want to bind your upper `div` or `nav` to the Vue instance.

Add an ID to it: `<nav id="my_nav">`

then on a Vue instance you can:

```
var a_vue_instance = new Vue({
    el: '#my_nav',
    data: {
        title: 'test',
    },
}
```

Comment: I did like this, but it is dissapearing after one sec, and the text is not for example dashboard but {{test}}

Comment: Property or method "title" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure to declare reactive data properties in the data option

Comment: For your second issue, post your code so we can see what's the problem.

Comment: data() {
            return {
                title: 'test',
            }
and in blade: <p style="text-align:center; color:white;">@{{ title }}</p>

Comment: edit your question and paste your code there, comments won't be long enough for your codes.

Comment: Okay i did it, see above

Comment: is your `<p>` inside a `<div>` that is bound to your **Vue** instance? say <div id="app"> then your **Vue** is bound like, `el: '#app'`?

Comment: But my navbar is created in blade, then I am importing it to vue templemates

Comment: so what I can do?

Comment: Make everything clear in your question so that others may try to give an answer. :)